# AWS Serverless PCI-DSS Compliance

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, pci-compliance, pci-dss

I noticed recently that Amazon got API Gateway and Lambda PCI-DSS certified. I would be interested to know what that does imply regarding the isolated network consideration, specifically:

- Is Amazon Lambda execution considered to be an isolated network, protected by a firewall?
- Is Amazon Lambda fulfilling the server IP masking property?

In essence, I would:

- Open an API allowing credit card processing over HTTPS with API
  Gateway
- Encrypt this data inside a Lambda function, using the Key
  Management Service
- Store the encrypted cards at rest in DynamoDB

Could this architecture be considered PCI-DSS compliant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using managed services is a great idea, it's more secure by default, and lets you focus on providing the functionality.

Lambda functions can be isolated in a VPC, so the firewall requirements are taken care of. Req 1.3 asks for a DMZ, where there is no direct connection into the private CDE. This is generally done with a NAT and public and private subnets ([reference here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-quick-start-reference-deployment-standardized-architecture-for-pci-dss/)). Using the API gateway may allow you to avoid that direct connection, but presumably you still need to call a payment processing gateway from your lambda function, in that case you still need the NAT anyway according to the AWS [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html):

> When you add VPC configuration to a Lambda function, it can only access resources in that VPC. If a Lambda function needs to access both VPC resources and the public Internet, the VPC needs to have a Network Address Translation (NAT) instance inside the VPC.

I would also check that logging and code deployment are handled in a PCI compliant manner.

I'd also point out that the architecture, while important, is basically only 1/12th of becoming PCI compliant, so is not going to necessarily make a big difference in the scheme of things.

Comment: This slideshare popped up a few days ago, not many details but at least provides some support to the idea of using serverless for PCI compliance: https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/how-to-handle-pci-and-hipaa-compliance-with-serverless-architecture-srv214